# How do i save a Quartz configuration to a file, in a WPF project?

Tags: wpf, quartz.net

I am building a WPF application which allows user to create Reminders in a calendar, and for each Reminder user can set the Name, Notes, Date, Alarm and if/at which frequency Alarm should repeat, snooze time, autodismiss, type...Of the Reminder.

After reading about it seems the best idea was to use a Scheduler, which i did using Quartz.Net (3.0.7)

With the code below, i can load Jobs and triggers, from a file, and start the scheduler. However is it really reliable way to handle the saving that way.

I read that the way "saving" is handled in Quartz is through a JobStoe, using a ADO.NET, but that seems very complex to me to implement and i am wondering if there is a simpler way to save my data that i don't see ?

Basically i just want to save all my Reminders to a file like a json file that would allow me the get the same application state as it was before it shutdown.

```
public class QuartzDynamicTest
    {
        public List<JobsAndTriggers> LstobjJobsAndTriggers { get; set; }

        public QuartzDynamicTest()
        {
            // LstobjJobsAndTriggers would be loaded from a repository:
            // Every time a user creates a nex reminder a new JobsAndTriggers is added to the list, and CreateAllJobsAndTriggers would be called
            LstobjJobsAndTriggers = new List<JobsAndTriggers>();
            LstobjJobsAndTriggers.Add(new JobsAndTriggers { jobIdentityKey = "JOB1", TriggerIdentityKey = "TRIGGER1", jobData_MethodName = "JOB1_METHOD()", ScheduleIntervalInSec = 5 });
            LstobjJobsAndTriggers.Add(new JobsAndTriggers { jobIdentityKey = "JOB2", TriggerIdentityKey = "TRIGGER2", jobData_MethodName = "JOB2_METHOD()", ScheduleIntervalInSec = 10 });        

            CreateAllJobsAndTriggers(LstobjJobsAndTriggers).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }

        public static async Task CreateAllJobsAndTriggers(List<JobsAndTriggers> lstJobsAndTriggers)

        {
            IScheduler scheduler;
            IJobDetail job = null;
            ITrigger trigger = null;

            var schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
            scheduler = schedulerFactory.GetScheduler().Result;
            scheduler.Start().Wait();


            foreach (var JobandTrigger in lstJobsAndTriggers)
            {              

                JobKey jobKey = JobKey.Create(JobandTrigger.jobIdentityKey);

                job = JobBuilder.Create<DemoJob1>().
                   WithIdentity(jobKey)
                   .UsingJobData("MethodName", JobandTrigger.jobData_MethodName)
                   .Build();

                trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity(JobandTrigger.TriggerIdentityKey)
                .StartNow()
                .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInSeconds(JobandTrigger.ScheduleIntervalInSec).WithRepeatCount(1)              
                )
                .Build();

                await scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);               
            }
            // Save infos about scheduler...?
        }

    }
```

Comment: You can serialise an object to disk and later deserialise back to in memory objects. Xml or json. If you use datacontractserialiser then you just need a public class, public properties. Those properties can include lists if similar complex objects. You shouid easily be able to find examples. Save your file to appdata. ( Google also).

Comment: Cheers Andy, i ended up using a JsonSerializer to save/load my list of jobs and triggers.